# Efficient way to fold list in scala, while avoiding allocations and vars

Tags: scala, optimization, functional-programming

I have a bunch of items in a list, and I need to analyze the content to find out how many of them are "complete". I started out with partition, but then realized that I didn't need to two lists back, so I switched to a fold:

```
val counts = groupRows.foldLeft( (0,0) )( (pair, row) => 
     if(row.time == 0) (pair._1+1,pair._2) 
     else (pair._1, pair._2+1)
   )
```

but I have a lot of rows to go through for a lot of parallel users, and it is causing a lot of GC activity (assumption on my part...the GC *could* be from other things, but I suspect this since I understand it will allocate a new tuple on every item folded).

for the time being, I've rewritten this as

```
var complete = 0
var incomplete = 0
list.foreach(row => if(row.time != 0) complete += 1 else incomplete += 1)
```

which fixes the GC, but introduces vars.

I was wondering if there was a way of doing this without using vars while also not abusing the GC?

**EDIT:**

Hard call on the answers I've received. A var implementation seems to be considerably faster on large lists (like by 40%) than even a tail-recursive optimized version that is more functional but should be equivalent.

The first answer from dhg seems to be on-par with the performance of the tail-recursive one, implying that the size pass is super-efficient...in fact, when optimized it runs very slightly faster than the tail-recursive one on my hardware.

Comment: It sounds like you have a lot of items and frequently count the ones finished/unfinished.  Could you instead maintain two counters in the companion object, bumping one when an item is added to the list (in a constructor?) and adjusting the counts (in the setter for time) when time != 0?

Comment: I agree with the other comment. The fold question is a red herring. "I have a lot of rows to go through for a lot of parallel users" means you have parallel jobs completing and you want a count of completed jobs. Either bump a count on Future.onComplete, or aggregate and trigger on that completing (i.e. wait for all done).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you've already accepted an answer, but you rightly mention that that solution will traverse the list twice. The way to do it efficiently is with recursion.

```
def counts(xs: List[...], complete: Int = 0, incomplete: Int = 0): (Int,Int) = 
  xs match {
    case Nil => (complete, incomplete)
    case row :: tail => 
      if (row.time == 0) counts(tail, complete + 1, incomplete)
      else               counts(tail, complete, incomplete + 1)
  }
```

This is effectively just a customized `fold`, except we use 2 accumulators which are just `Int`s (primitives) instead of tuples (reference types). It should also be just as efficient a while-loop with vars - in fact, the bytecode should be identical.

Comment: I like your answer, but I discovered that `Iterator.partition` has a pretty cool implementation that allows for a very simple one-pass solution.  See my updated answer.

Comment: I updated your benchmark to include some of the other answers, and also increased the list size (since I'm interested in the the n^a behavior being very apparent). Yours is as fast as the var implementation, and interestingly, the view one from Dave is beyond slow. http://pastebin.com/ZDzvekHF

Answer (score 11):

The cleanest two-pass solution is probably to just use the built-in `count` method:

```
val complete = groupRows.count(_.time == 0)
val counts = (complete, groupRows.size - complete)
```

But you can do it in one pass if you use `partition` on an iterator:

```
val (complete, incomplete) = groupRows.iterator.partition(_.time == 0)
val counts = (complete.size, incomplete.size)
```

This works because the new returned iterators are linked behind the scenes and calling `next` on one will cause it to move the original iterator forward until it finds a matching element, but it remembers the non-matching elements for the other iterator so that they don't need to be recomputed.

---

Example of the one-pass solution:

```
scala> val groupRows = List(Row(0), Row(1), Row(1), Row(0), Row(0)).view.map{x => println(x); x}
scala> val (complete, incomplete) = groupRows.iterator.partition(_.time == 0)
Row(0)
Row(1)
complete: Iterator[Row] = non-empty iterator
incomplete: Iterator[Row] = non-empty iterator
scala> val counts = (complete.size, incomplete.size)
Row(1)
Row(0)
Row(0)
counts: (Int, Int) = (3,2)
```

Comment: Lol I forgot about count. Here I am using fold :P

Comment: Is there any kind of built-in like partition that would let you get the counts as a pair? This algorithm (on a List, at least) requires walking the list twice (once for count, and once for size).

Comment: +1 for one-pass. On count: some months ago, I got called on using fold for count, too; there must be something wrong with method-consciousness there.  I remember Odersky said somewhere there's "50 or so" to learn.  Is "count" so ordinary that the brain ignores it? Maybe it just needs a fancier name. Or some love, like Charlie Brown's tree.  I know, "tally".

Comment: I don't have much intuition about the efficiency of iterator methods - and that's partly why I would avoid them, apart from the fact they're mutable by definition. But I would guess they're relatively slow and a benchmark confirms this. http://pastebin.com/NfrGPdcK Your first version for 100k runs on a 100 element list takes 50ms, my version takes 58ms, and your "one pass" version takes 333ms. Seems to show that traversing a list to get its length is only as expensive or maybe less than updating an accumulator for each element.

Comment: @Luigi, Very interesting!  Thanks for doing the analysis!

Comment: After running through benchmarks and seeing Luigi's code, I've changed my choice of accepted answer to his; however, your answers were still extremely helpful and insightful. Thanks!

Comment: I happened to be looking at the code because of a PR and noticed that "remember the non-matching elements" means "copy to a queue". https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/collection/Iterator.scala#L528 but I also see opportunities at IndexedSeqLike and also Vector that has a custom iterator. Oder?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's just me, but I prefer using the various specialized folds (.size, .exists, .sum, .product) if they are available.  I find it clearer and less error-prone than the heavy-duty power of general folds.

```
val complete = groupRows.view.filter(_.time==0).size
(complete, groupRows.length - complete)
```

Comment: It seems like that will create _something_ new (not sure how view works), and then walk it to get a size...seems like a 2n op.

Comment: Actually, on a List, a 3n op, since you are walking it again on groupRows.length

Comment: No, the .view is a constant-time operation that makes succeeding operations lazy, so the first line is a 1n operation. The .length in the second line does make it a 2*n operation, albeit with no more than constant allocations. The selected answer is actually equivalent to mine, I simply forgot about the .count operation

Comment: I see converting to a view as a constant-time op, but how does size become constant time if the underlying data structure is a list...or does the view suddenly start tracking the size as you walk the filter?

Comment: See the benchmarks. The lazy evaluation evidently makes things horrifically slow for long lists. This was literally 4 orders of _magnitude_ slower for large lists than any of the others.

Answer (score 2):

OK, inspired by the answers above, but really wanting to only pass over the list once and avoid GC, I decided that, in the face of a lack of direct API support, I would add this to my central library code:

```
class RichList[T](private val theList: List[T]) {
  def partitionCount(f: T => Boolean): (Int, Int) = {
    var matched = 0
    var unmatched = 0
    theList.foreach(r => { if (f(r)) matched += 1 else unmatched += 1 })
    (matched, unmatched)
  }
}

object RichList {
  implicit def apply[T](list: List[T]): RichList[T] = new RichList(list)
}
```

Then in my application code (if I've imported the implicit), I can write var-free expressions:

```
val (complete, incomplete) = groupRows.partitionCount(_.time != 0)
```

and get what I want: an optimized GC-friendly routine that prevents me from polluting the rest of the program with vars.

However, I then saw Luigi's benchmark, and updated it to:

- Use a longer list so that multiple passes on the list were more obvious in the numbers
- Use a boolean function in all cases, so that we are comparing things fairly

http://pastebin.com/2XmrnrrB

The var implementation is definitely considerably faster, even though Luigi's routine should be identical (as one would expect with optimized tail recursion). Surprisingly, dhg's dual-pass original is just as fast (slightly faster if compiler optimization is on) as the tail-recursive one. I do not understand why.

Comment: In a perfect world, you would make this a pimp of Traversable (or even TraversableOnce), not List.  There's no reason this shouldn't be available on Sets, Maps, and Streams, as well as Lists.

Comment: I don't have post-its with Odersky quotes on my monitor or anything, but he often writes firmly (not to say rants) on the ML about cognitive overload and the mental cost of adding to an API.

Comment: @DaveGriffith Great. I'm not overly familiar with the mass of traits and superclasses in collections yet. Great tip.

Answer (score 2):

How about this one? No import tax.

```
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import scala.collection.Traversable
import scala.collection.mutable.Builder

case class Count(n: Int, total: Int) {
  def not = total - n
}
object Count {
  implicit def cbf[A]: CanBuildFrom[Traversable[A], Boolean, Count] = new CanBuildFrom[Traversable[A], Boolean, Count] {
    def apply(): Builder[Boolean, Count] = new Counter
    def apply(from: Traversable[A]): Builder[Boolean, Count] = apply()
  }
}
class Counter extends Builder[Boolean, Count] {
  var n = 0
  var ttl = 0
  override def +=(b: Boolean) = { if (b) n += 1; ttl += 1; this }
  override def clear() { n = 0 ; ttl = 0 }
  override def result = Count(n, ttl)
}

object Counting extends App {
  val vs = List(4, 17, 12, 21, 9, 24, 11)
  val res: Count = vs map (_ % 2 == 0)
  Console println s"${vs} have ${res.n} evens out of ${res.total}; ${res.not} were odd."
  val res2: Count = vs collect { case i if i % 2 == 0 => i > 10 }
  Console println s"${vs} have ${res2.n} evens over 10 out of ${res2.total}; ${res2.not} were smaller."
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this...I was not aware of the builder stuff...this is really cool.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It was kind of tongue-in-cheek, so I expected at least a chuckle.  But after you changed your green check, I actually decided I liked it, as a one-liner (use-site). Probably there's a clever way to generalize it using scalaz.

Answer (score 0):

It is slightly tidier to use a mutable accumulator pattern, like so, especially if you can re-use your accumulator:

```
case class Accum(var complete = 0, var incomplete = 0) {
  def inc(compl: Boolean): this.type = {
    if (compl) complete += 1 else incomplete += 1
    this
  }
}
val counts = groupRows.foldLeft( Accum() ){ (a, row) => a.inc( row.time == 0 ) }
```

If you really want to, you can hide your vars as private; if not, you still are a lot more self-contained than the pattern with vars.

Answer (score 0):

You could just calculate it using the difference like so:

```
def counts(groupRows: List[Row]) = {
  val complete = groupRows.foldLeft(0){ (pair, row) => 
    if(row.time == 0) pair + 1 else pair
  }
  (complete, groupRows.length - complete)
}
```